# Mysql MATCH AGAINST not working for latin characters - NOT issue with length of the word

Tags: sql, mysql, database, match-against

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users u WHERE MATCH(u.first_name, u.last_name) AGAINST ('+áééxcv*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I am trying to get the result where first_name of the record is áééxcv (latin chars). I am getting other records in the results starting with charcter "a" (normal "a") but not the expected one.

I get the correct result when I run query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users u u.first_name = 'áééxcv';
```

Even though MATCH... Against is working as expected in case of normal English characters but not with latin characters.

**DB has charset/collation:** utf8mb4/utf8mb4_unicode_ci

**users table collation:** utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: the minimum are 3 letters, you need to change it if you want single character

Comment: @nbk there is no issue while searching the less number of character, it works fine even if I search with single letter (normal english alphabet). It fails only when I use words starting with latin letters

Comment: Please post your table with data as text so that we can reproduce your error